# Android Studio Project Encoding Error

Tags: android, android-studio

Every time when i start a new project, after gradle finishes it shows this warning to me.

```
Warning:The project encoding (windows-1252) does not match the encoding specified in the Gradle build files (UTF-8). This can lead to serious bugs.
```

Is anyone know how to overcome this issue?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When you get that warning, click on Open File Encoding Settings. Then change both IDE Encoding and Project Encoding to UTF-8 from the select box. You can also change the default encoding at the bottom of the settings menu.

Comment: Make sure you do a gradle sync after to release the error.

Answer (score 9):

In your Android Studio open **File >> Settings >> Editor >> File Encodings**

And then set **IDE Encoding, Project Encoding** and **Default encoding for properties file** to UTF-8 as shown in the image below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Make Sure All Encoding are UTF-8, Which Means IDE, Project and Default

Answer (score 0):

Close your Android Studio projects

Now Goto "C:\Users.AndroidStudio3.5\System in that folder remove caches folder.

Now Open Android studio and Sync your projects.