# What is project encoding in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, encoding, utf-8, windows-1252

I was initially having problem of mismatched File encoding. That i fixed but what does that mean Project encoding and IDE encoding?

And which encoding to use and what are the limitations of other encodings?

I am new to android and programming too. So, please provide a detailed answer or link to find more info on that.

Comment: visit this : http://tools.android.com/knownissues/encoding

Comment: possible Answers on stackoverflow.. http://stackoverflow.com/a/30012572/6334037 http://stackoverflow.com/a/30498383/6334037

Comment: @userJP this answer shows how to correct that mismatching.

Comment: I wanna know what does it actually mean?